# Error uploading Autodesk design automation, dotnet Core..... 1 rfa and 1 big Json file to pass as input

Tags: c#, ajax, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-designautomation

The Revit Addin is working perfectly and I have also converted correctly for Design automation. I have debugged it with local debugger. It worked perfect.
So I can say app bundle is perfectly doing well.

Now coming to the web application code, it works perfect until last line of "workItemStatus".
I need a rfa file and a big Json file as input file, to run the code. Both together will be 1 mb in size. But code is stack (endlessly waiting) when uploading file, workitem does not start.
I read in another stackoverflow post, that Forge does not allow more than 16kb upload to oss bucket by..... 
 Url = string.Format("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{0}/objects/{1}", bucketKey, inputFileNameOSS)
That post says, I will need to upload bigger files to another cloud service and use the signed-in URL instead of Forge oss bucket.

The code looks correct while debugging and it is stack, when it reach to the line
***WorkItemStatus workItemStatus = await _designAutomation.CreateWorkItemAsync(workItemSpec);***

I have debugged the code, looks like perfectly working until "workItemStatus" value, in DesignAutomationController.cs "StartWorkItem".
Every Key and Value looks perfectly passed.
Is it because of the file size ? As the Json file is big, I am uploading it like the other input (.rfa/.rvt) files.

````
string callbackUrl = string.Format("{0}/api/forge/callback/designautomation?id={1}&outputFileName={2}", OAuthController.GetAppSetting("FORGE_WEBHOOK_URL"), browerConnectionId, outputFileNameOSS);
            WorkItem workItemSpec = new WorkItem()
            {
                ActivityId = activityName,
                Arguments = new Dictionary<string, IArgument>()
                {
                    { "inputFile", inputFileArgument },
                    { "inputJsonFile", inputFileArgument1 },
                    { "outputFile", outputFileArgument },
                    { "onComplete", new XrefTreeArgument { Verb = Verb.Post, Url = callbackUrl } }
                }
            };
            ***WorkItemStatus workItemStatus = await _designAutomation.CreateWorkItemAsync(workItemSpec);***

            return Ok(new { WorkItemId = workItemStatus.Id }); ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read in another stackoverflow post, that Forge does not allow more than 16kb upload to oss bucket by..

The 16kb limit is on a `payload` of design automation endpoints including the workitem. The limits are defined [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/rate-limits/da-rate-limits/). If the workitem payload exceeds 16kb you will see an error `HTTP 413 Payload Too Large`.

To send large json inputs to design automation, you may first upload the json to OSS (or even another storage service such as Amazon S3). Then call the workitem with a signed url to the json file (similar to the signed url for the rfa file).

**Edit:**
 1. Large JSON files can be uploaded to OSS using Data Management [endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/). 
 2. A signed URL with `read` access can then be obtained for that object using [endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/signedresources-:id-PUT/). 
 3. The URL obtained can then be passed to Design Automation workitem payload as an `input argument`, instead of embedding the json contents into the payload.

Comment: OK. Maximum permitted size for a work item’s JSON payload
16. Using Data management API.

Comment: Yes, Data Management API can be used to upload json files as well. Since you have already uploaded rfa file, I am guessing you already know how to.

Here is the API endpoint just in case:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/

You will then need to create a signed URL with write access:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-signed-POST/

The url obtained can then be passed on to Design Automation workitem.